# PHP change method/function visibility

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to write a PHP class in which I change the visibility of a few methods from protected to public. I believe I remember you can do this in C++, but I did a few searches and I am not coming up with anything for that in PHP. Does anyone know if this is even possible in PHP?

For example, suppose this class:

```
 class ABC {
     protected function foo() {
          // Do something
     }
  }

  class DEG extends ABC {
      // can I make foo public now?
  }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can change the visibility of members when deriving from a base class like this:

```
class Base
{
    protected function foo() {}
}

class Derived extends Base
{
    public function foo() { return parent::foo(); }
}
```

You can also do the same with properties (redefine a `protected` property as `public`).

However, be aware that if the base property is `private` then you will not actually increase its accessibility but rather declare *a new property with the same name*. This is not an issue with functions, as if you tried to call a `private` base method you would immediately get a runtime error.

Comment: Yes, and this is actually different from C++ (where you can't 'upper' the visibility modifier in derived class).

Comment: Can you show us how to change the visibility of a property from protected in the base to public in the derived? Thanks!

Comment: @NickStrupat: [This way](http://ideone.com/iRKThk). The only caveat is that if the protected version is initialized with a constant outside the constructor, redeclaring the property resets it to `null`.

Comment: "This is not an issue with functions" - Well, the same applies to functions/methods as it does with properties. "if the base _method_ is private then you will not actually increase its _visibility_ but rather declare a new _method_ with the same name." The difference between properties and methods is what happens when you try to access one that has not been defined, an E_NOTICE and E_ERROR (fatal) respectively.

Answer (score 4):

- You can overwrite a method in a derived class to highten it´s visibility (e.g. protected->public). Make the new function return it´s parent.
- You cannot do so to limit it´s visibility (e.g. public->protected), but you can implement a method that checks the backtrace for the caller and thwors an exception if it´s a foreign class.
- You can always use the [reflection API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) to do all kinds of changes to the visibility.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it can be done. Quoting from [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)..

> The visibility of a property or method can be defined by prefixing the
>   declaration with the keywords public, protected or private. Class
>   members declared public can be accessed everywhere. Members declared
>   protected can be accessed only within the class itself and by
>   inherited and parent classes. Members declared as private may only be
>   accessed by the class that defines the member.

And the example from there as well..

```
class MyClass
{
    public $public = 'Public';
    protected $protected = 'Protected';
    private $private = 'Private';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj = new MyClass();
echo $obj->public; // Works
echo $obj->protected; // Fatal Error
echo $obj->private; // Fatal Error
$obj->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected and Private
```

**Edit** : Yes, you can change visibility of public and protected members. Another example from PHP manual..

```
/**
 * Define MyClass2
 */
class MyClass2 extends MyClass
{
    // We can redeclare the public and protected method, but not private
    protected $protected = 'Protected2';

    function printHello()
    {
        echo $this->public;
        echo $this->protected;
        echo $this->private;
    }
}

$obj2 = new MyClass2();
echo $obj2->public; // Works
echo $obj2->private; // Undefined
echo $obj2->protected; // Fatal Error
$obj2->printHello(); // Shows Public, Protected2, Undefined

?>
```

Comment: This example does not demonstrate the _change in visibility_ of any class members, it simply demonstrates the _difference_ between private, protected and public visibility. "you can change visibility of public and protected members" - you can only _increase_ the visibility of class members, so in this sense you can't actually _change_ the visibility of a class member that is already public.